# The JQuery code i'm using to toggle a div on and off isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm trying to complete this project, and finally managed to insert an information div, which is to be seen when one of the album divs is clicked. However, the code isn't working. I've tried everything I could, and this is really holding me. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="queendisco.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="queen.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="teste"></div>
<div class="discoestudio">
     <div class="linha">
        <div class="album" id="queenI"></div>
        <div class="album" id="queenII"><br></div>
        <div class="album" id="sha"><br></div>
        <div class="album2" id="theopera"><br></div>
        <div class="album2" id="theraces"><br></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="linha2">
        <div class="album" id="notw"><br></div>
        <div class="album" id="jazz"><br></div>
        <div class="album" id="thegame"><br></div>
        <div class="album2" id="flash"><br></div>
        <div class="album2" id="hotspace"><br></div>
    </div>
        <div class="linha3">
        <div class="album4" id="theworks"><br></div>
        <div class="album4" id="kindof"><br></div>
        <div class="album4" id="miracle"><br></div>
        <div class="album3" id="innuendo"><br></div>
        <div class="album3" id="madein"><br></div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then the CSS

```
body {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
}
.discoestudio {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 640px;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -4;
    }
.teste {
    width: 640px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #ff0000;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 428px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    }
.album {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 0;
    }

.album:hover {
    transform: scale(2.1); 
    transform-origin: left top;
    z-index: 1;
    }

.album2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 0;
    }
.album2:hover {
    transform: scale(2.1); 
    transform-origin: right top;
    z-index: 1;
    }
.album3 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 0;
    }
.album3:hover {
    transform: scale(2.1); 
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    transform-style: flat;
    z-index: 1;
    }
.album4 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 0;
    }
.album4:hover {
    transform: scale(2.1); 
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform-style: flat;
    z-index: 1;
    }
.linha {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    }
.linha2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
.linha3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
#queenI {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KU49O2S.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    }

#queenII {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/mYirR51.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#sha {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Q72zBuk.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#theopera {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ot58zUZ.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#theraces {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/RRBqAcV.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#notw {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Q4basfN.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#jazz {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/VdhcaPL.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#thegame {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/GACdUCy.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#flash {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/PhHgSmw.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#hotspace {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/j1HY5FV.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#theworks {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/CFROuSj.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#kindof {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/pVY63E5.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#miracle {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/OiYAK1N.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#innuendo {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/84TP2Cc.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#madein {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/oyNI3u0.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

And finally, the JS

```
$('#theraces').click(function() {
    $('.teste').show();
});
```

Could someone help me? I'm really stuck at this part! :(

Comment: What's not working? It looks like the `div` with `.teste` is empty.... what do you expect to see?

Comment: As of now, i'm just testing the JS functionality, expecting the .teste background to appear, just as if it wasn't displayed as none.

Comment: Your example works ok for me... https://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ccq9/

Comment: Well, this is really strange...

Answer (score 3):

You put your script at the top of the page where it will run before the `#theraces` div is loaded. You should always wrap your handlers in `$(...)` so that they run after the DOM is ready, i.e.,

```
$(function() {
  $('#theraces').click(function() {
    $('.teste').show();
  });
});
```

which is an abbreviation for `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yous should add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="queen.js"></script>
```

after loading complete body.

So, add your script before body closing tag

Comment: Thank you a lot, sir! You (and all the good friends on the topic) saved my day!